# Specify a nil in command line args

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line-interface

I have a command line tool which generates a flat json doc.  Imagine this:

```
$ ruby gen-json.rb --foo bar --baz qux
{
    "foo": "bar"
    "baz": "qux"
}
```

What I want is this to work:

```
$ ruby gen-json.rb --foo $'\0' --baz qux
{
    "foo": null,
    "baz": "qux"
}
```

Instead of null I get an empty string.  To simplify the problem even further consider this:

```
$ cat nil-args.rb
puts "argv[0] is nil" if ARGV[0].nil?
puts "argv[0] is an empty string" if ARGV[0] == ""
puts "argv[1] is nil" if ARGV[1].nil?
```

I want to run it like this and get this output:

```
$ ruby nil-args.rb $'\0' foo
argv[0] is nil
```

But instead I get

```
argv[0] is an empty string
```

I suspect this is (arguably) a bug in the ruby interpreter.  It is treating argv[0] as a C string which null terminates.

Comment: Because a string with char number 0 in ASCII is empty string?

Comment: ASCII code 0 is NUL, which C uses to terminate string arrays.  So you can't have nul in a c-string.  I am suggesting the ruby interpreter should read in a string and if it is only NUL then set the var to nil.  That probably breaks a bunch of things because the type of ARGV[0] is no longer String.  So I don't think what I want is possible.

Comment: +1, but please google the phrase "select isn't broken" about it being a bug.

Comment: A possible workaround is that you *can* pass NUL characters through a *pipe*. But **you cannot store NULs in a variable**.

Answer (score 3):

Command line arguments are *always* strings. You will need to use a sentinel to indicate arguments you want to treat otherwise.

Comment: Couldn't it be a string containing one character - the NUL character?

Comment: The problem is that the NUL is invisible at the C  level, so it's not visible in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you *literally* cannot do what you are proposing. It's a fundamental limitation of the shell you are using. You can only ever pass string arguments into a script.

It has already been mentioned in a comment but the output you get with the \0 method you tried makes perfect sense. The null terminator technically is an empty string.

Also consider that accessing any element of an array that has not yet been defined will always be nil.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[10].nil?
#=> true
```

A possible solution, however, would be for your program to work like this:

```
$ ruby gen-json.rb --foo --baz qux
{
    "foo": null,
    "baz": "qux"
}
```

So when you have a double minus sign argument followed by another double minus sign argument, you infer that the first one was null. You will need to write your own command line option parser to achieve this, though.

Here is a very very simple example script that seems to work (but likely has edge cases and other problems):

```
require 'pp'

json = {}

ARGV.each_cons(2) do |key, value|
  next unless key.start_with? '--'
  json[key] = value.start_with?('--') ? nil : value
end

pp json
```

Would that work for your purposes? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby treats EVERYTHING except `nil` and `false` as `true`. Therefore, any empty string will evaluate as true (as well as `0` or `0.0`).

You can force the nil behaviour by having something like this:

```
ARGV.map! do |arg|
  if arg.empty?
    nil
  else
    arg
  end
end
```

this way, any empty strings will be transformed in a reference to `nil`.

Comment: I want to be able to differentiate between nil and an empty string.

Comment: Then I don't see where your problem resides.
You already are, by default, differentiating between `nil` and an empty string (in a manner that when you pass an empty string as an argument, it will NOT evaluate as `nil`), but what you apparently wants is NOT to do it.

Exactly **when** do you want and empty string to be mapped to `nil` and **when** do you want an empty string to be treated as it is?

Comment: A (ruby) string containing NUL is different than an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to decide on a special character to mean nil.  I would suggest `"\0"` (double-quotes ensures the literal string *backslash zero* is passed in).  You can then use a special type converter in `OptionParser`:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'json'

values = {}
parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("--foo VAL",:nulldetect) { |val| values[:foo] = val }
  opts.on("--bar VAL",:nulldetect) { |val| values[:foo] = val }

  opts.accept(:nulldetect) do |string|
    if string == '\0'
      nil
    else
      string
    end
  end
end

parser.parse!

puts values.to_json
```

Obviously, this requires you to be explicit about the flags you accept, but if you want to accept any flag, you can certainly just hand-jam the `if` statements for checking for `"\0"`

As a side note, you can have flags be optional, but you get the empty string passed to the block, e.g.

```
opts.on("--foo [VAL]") do |val|
  # if --foo is passed w/out args, val is empty string
end
```

So, you'd still need a stand-in